# Recently uploaded images not found using cloudflare

Tags: image, caching, cloudflare

I'm using cloudflare as CDN (fully optimization) and I have a problem when I upload a new image; the image is not available at the domain (it's available if I use the server IP). The problem is that Cloudflare does not cache inmediatly, so I think I can solve this in two different ways:

- A page rule in cloudflare (or some other option) to indicate that if a resource on the image directory is not available on cdn cache, try to load directly from the server or cache it in that moment.
- A request to cloudflare to cache the new image when I upload it.

But I have been looking for how to implement one of this ways, and I have not found nothing related. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.